# Why it is sufficient to show $|f'(z)-1|<1$?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, analytic-geometry, convex-analysis

According to an article entitled ["On the Univalency of Certain Analytic Functions" by Wang et al. (2006)](http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/125_05_JIPAM/125_05.pdf), we have to show that $|f'(z)-1|<1$ in order to find the radius of univalency for the class $Q(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$. Note that $Q(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ denotes the class of functions of the form
$$f(z)=z+a_{2}z^{2}+\cdots$$
which are analytic in open unit disk, $D=\{z:|z|<1\}$, and satisfy the condition

$$\mathfrak{Re} \left\{\frac{\alpha f(z)}{z}+\beta f'(z)\right\}>\gamma \qquad (\alpha, \beta >0;\ 0 \leq \gamma<\alpha+ \beta\leq 1;\ z\in D)$$

Why it is sufficient to show that $|f'(z)-1|<1$?

Comment: See [A complex map with “bounded” derivative is injective](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/159746/79365)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $g(z)=f(z)-z$. The condition $|f'(z)-1|<1$ translates into $|g'(z)|<1$. Given distinct points $z,\zeta\in D$, integrate along the line segment between them to obtain $|g(z)-g(\zeta)|<|z-\zeta|$. Hence $f(z)\ne f(\zeta)$.